# Convergence of sequence averages of rolls of a die to the expected value.

Tags: probability, statistics

While I was reading about the expected value on the Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) one image attracted my attention:
[image]

Legend of an image: "An illustration of the convergence of sequence averages of rolls of a die to the expected value of 3.5 as the number of rolls (trials) grows."

My question is - how can you describe function responsible for this red convergence graph? Is it just a function:

$$f(r)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_{i}}{r}, \hspace{2 mm} for \hspace{2 mm} x_{i}\in X, \hspace{2 mm} where \hspace{2 mm} X \hspace{2 mm} is \hspace{2 mm} the \hspace{2 mm} set \hspace{2 mm} of \hspace{2 mm} values \hspace{2 mm} for \hspace{2 mm} all \hspace{2 mm} dice \hspace{2 mm} rolls?$$

Comment: Yes, the red line is the mean of the $r$ trials, as you have it.

Comment: Oh, that's great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very formally, I would write :

$\begin{align}
f_X : \mathbb{N}^* &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
n &\rightarrow \dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i}{n}
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
\text{where}\ \ \ \  & \forall i \in \mathbb{N}^*,\ x_i\ \text{is the result of the}\ i^{th}\ \text{die roll}\ ;\\
&X = \{x_i\ |\ i \in \mathbb{N}^*\}.
\end{align}$

I think using the subscript $X$ in $f_X$ is important because although $X$ shouldn't be a parameter of $f$, $f$ depends of $X$.

Comment: Nice one :) Thank you!